# Slow range query on a multikey index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I have a MongoDB collection named `post` with **35 million** objects. The collection has two secondary indexes defined as follows.

```
> db.post.getIndexKeys()
[
    {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    {
        "namespace" : 1,
        "domain" : 1,
        "post_id" : 1
    },
    {
        "namespace" : 1,
        "post_time" : 1,
        "tags" : 1  // this is an array field
    }
]
```

I expect the following query, which simply filters by `namespace` and `post_time`, to run in a reasonable time without scanning all objects.

```
>db.post.find({post_time: {"$gte" : ISODate("2013-04-09T00:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2013-04-09T01:00:00Z")}, namespace: "my_namespace"}).count()
7408
```

However, it takes MongoDB at least ten minutes to retrieve the result and, curiously, it manages to scan **70 million** objects to do the job according to the `explain` function.

```
> db.post.find({post_time: {"$gte" : ISODate("2013-04-09T00:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2013-04-09T01:00:00Z")}, namespace: "my_namespace"}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor namespace_1_post_time_1_tags_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 7408,
    "nscannedObjects" : 69999186,
    "nscanned" : 69999186,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 69999186,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 69999186,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 378967,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 290048,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "namespace" : [
            [
                "my_namespace",
                "my_namespace"
            ]
        ],
        "post_time" : [
            [
                ISODate("2013-04-09T00:00:00Z"),
                ISODate("292278995-01--2147483647T07:12:56.808Z")
            ]
        ],
        "tags" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "localhost:27017"
}
```

The difference between the number of objects and the number of scans must be caused by the lengths of the tag arrays (which are all equal to 2). Still, I don't understand why `post_time` filter does not make use of the index.

Can you tell me what I might be missing?

(I am working on a descent machine with 24 cores and 96 GB RAM. I am using MongoDB 2.2.3.)

Comment: Has namespace got a very low cardinality?

Comment: Currently, there is only one distinct `namespace` value, which is the one I'm using.

Comment: Yea that is why, MongoDB must limit on the first field first, so it gets all `my_namespace` and then gets all docs between that date, etc etc, try reordering the index so the post_time is first

Comment: Doesn't the index tree contain `post_time` values too under the `my_namespace` branch? Why start scanning before narrowing down?

Comment: Just to be sure, I've created an index with key `{post_time: 1, namespace: 1}` as you suggested. It still uses the old index if I filter by both `namespace` and `post_time`. However, if I filter _only_ by `post_time`, it computes the result in a blink, as expected.

Comment: Hmm the old index must be winning the race condition, if you just try a `hint()` a sec does it all work as expected?

Comment: Even though the btree contains both fields compound indexs work in a certain way in MongoDB which means it will scan all namespaces for that value and then narrow down in date. Hmm trying to find a doc page that explains it well but there is no real good doc page on index internals from the google search though this post may help: http://emptysquare.net/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/

Comment: I see your point and it makes sense if you are worried on the index optimality. What I was worried was that the index was not being used at all. Now, I've found the reason. Please see my answer.

Thank you for the discussion and for the references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer in this question: [Order of $lt and $gt in MongoDB range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895888/order-of-lt-and-gt-in-mongodb-range-query?rq=1)

My index is a multikey index (on `tags`) and I am running a range query (on `post_time`). [Apparently](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4155), MongoDB cannot use both sides of the range as a filter in this case, so it just picks the `$gte` clause, which comes first. As my lower limit happens to be the lowest `post_time` value, MongoDB starts scanning all the objects.

Unfortunately, this is not the whole story. Trying to solve the problem, I created non-multikey indexes too but MongoDB insisted on using the bad one. That made me think that the problem was elsewhere. Finally, I had to drop the multikey index and create one without the `tags` field. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Dang I never knew that about `$gt` and `$lt` and miltikeys, nice find!

Comment: Using cursor.hint could also be a solution to make mongodb use the other index
(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint)