# MongoDB Multikey Compound Index - Need Help Understanding Bounds

Tags: mongodb

We've recently decided to revisit some of our MongoDB indexes and came across a peculiar result when using a compound index which contains a multikey part.

It's important to note that we're using v2.4.5

**TLDR**: When using a compound index with multikey part, **the bounds of a non-multikey** field used for range restriction are dropped.

I'll explain the problem with an example:

***Create some data***

```
db.demo.insert(
[{ "foo" : 1, "attr" : [  {  "name" : "a" },  {  "name" : "b" },  {  "name" : "c" } ]},
 { "foo" : 2, "attr" : [  {  "name" : "b" },  {  "name" : "c" },  {  "name" : "d" } ]},
 { "foo" : 3, "attr" : [  {  "name" : "c" },  {  "name" : "d" },  {  "name" : "e" } ]},
 { "foo" : 4, "attr" : [  {  "name" : "d" },  {  "name" : "e" },  {  "name" : "f" } ]}])
```

***Index***

```
db.demo.ensureIndex({'attr.name': 1, 'foo': 1})
```

***Query & Explain***

Query on 'attr.name' but constrain the range of the non-multikey field 'foo':

```
db.demo.find({foo: {$lt:3, $gt: 1}, 'attr.name': 'c'}).hint('attr.name_1_foo_1').explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor attr.name_1_foo_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "attr.name" : [
            [
                "c",
                "c"
            ]
        ],
        "foo" : [
            [
                -1.7976931348623157e+308,
                3
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, the range of 'foo' is not as defined in the query, one end is completely ignored which results in nscanned being larger than it should.

Changing the order of the range operands will alter the dropped end:

```
db.demo.find({foo: {$gt: 1, $lt:3}, 'attr.name': 'c'}).hint('attr.name_1_foo_1').explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor attr.name_1_foo_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "attr.name" : [
            [
                "c",
                "c"
            ]
        ],
        "foo" : [
            [
                1,
                1.7976931348623157e+308
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

We're either missing out on some multikey index basics, or we're facing a bug.

We've gone through similar topics, including:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/multikey$20bounds/mongodb-user/RKrsyzRwHrE/_i0SxdJV5qcJ
- [Order of $lt and $gt in MongoDB range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895888/order-of-lt-and-gt-in-mongodb-range-query?rq=1)

Unfortunately these posts address a different use-case where a range is set on the multikeyed value.

Other things we've tried to do:

- Change the compound index ordering, starting with the non-multikey field.
- Put the 'foo' value inside each of the subdocuments in the 'attr' array, index by ('attr.name', 'attr.foo') and do an $elemMatch on 'attr' with a range constraint on 'foo'.
- Use an $and operator when defining the range:

  ```
  db.demo.find({'attr.name': 'c', $and: [{num: {$lt: 3}}, {num: {$gt: 1}}]})
  ```
- Use MongoDB v2.5.4

None of the above had any effect (v2.5.4 made things worse by dumping both ends of the range completely).

**Any kind of help would be highly appreciated!**

Many Thanks,

Roi

Answer (score 2):

With compound indexes where one of the indexed fields is an array, MongoDB  will only use either a lower or upper bound for the range query to ensure correct matches are returned. See [SERVER-958](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-958) for an example where constraining to both upper and lower index bounds would not find the expected document.

If your range query is on the array field you can potentially use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to optimise your query within the expected index bounds.  As at MongoDB 2.4, the `$elemMatch` operator does not work on non-array fields so unfortunately this doesn't help your use case.  You can watch/upvote [SERVER-6050: Consider allowing $elemMatch applied to non arrays](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6050) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

There is also an open issue [SERVER-7959: Potentially unexpected scans with compound indexes when some fields are multikey](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7959) describing this behaviour.

Comment: Did you use different datSet? How come n:0?

Comment: @Stennie, It was late at night when I noticed your answer so I didn't notice the 'n:0' result which was mentioned by Asya as well. When trying this optimization on my hefty data set (as well as the demo), the bounds reported seem OK but the returned result is always empty. Any idea how to enjoy both the correct bounds and the correct results?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: should be the same data set but I've mixed up something when testing the answer; will re-test.

Comment: @RoiTal: Will recheck .. thought $elemMatch should do the trick but it's late for me as well :). Feel free to unaccept while I work on a corrected answer.

Comment: @RoiTal: Revised my answer, but unfortunately don't have a better solution for you yet :(

Comment: You can't use more than one array field in a compound index, so I think the workaround alluded to in SERVER-7959 is to ensure another index which is non-multikey. That may not be great if all of the documents matching the range of `foo` values need to be inspected to compare the `attr.name` array values.

Comment: @Stennie, Many thanks for your ongoing help - I really appreciate it :). The 'foo' field is stored outside of the array and always holds a scalar value, so there's no violation in this case. Creating a non-multikey index would probably not work very well for us, as attr.name is much more selective in our case than the 'foo' range. Maybe I didn't fully understand you, please let me know what you think.

Comment: @Stennie Finally, this issue seems to be fixed! See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15086

The problem was that the all the index was marked as "multikey", so the indexbound resolution was not correct

Comment: @jcoll There's indeed a fix for this in MongoDB 3.4 if you are using the default WiredTiger storage engine. My original answer was referring to MongoDB 2.4 and related Jira issues that pre-dated the ultimate fix in [SERVER-15086: Allow for efficient range queries over non-array fields in multikey indices](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15086). SERVER-15086 has a more detailed technical summary of the issue and resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The [$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.min/) and [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.max/) operators may help to work around this issue, by allowing you to explicitly specify the index bounds.

Example:

```
db.demo.find({foo: {$lt:3, $gt: 1}, 'attr.name': 'c'}).
 hint('attr.name_1_foo_1').
 min({'attr.name': 'c', foo: 1.000001}).
 max({'attr.name': 'c', foo: 3}).explain()
```

Result:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor attr.name_1_foo_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "start" : {
            "attr.name" : "c",
            "foo" : 1.000001
        },
        "end" : {
            "attr.name" : "c",
            "foo" : 3
        }
    }
}
```

There are some important caveats though:

1. $min is always inclusive (like $gte), and $max is always exclusive (like $lt). You may have to adjust your values to get the effect of $gt or $lte.
2. The fields in $min and $max must exactly match the fields in the index.
3. You can only have one set of index bounds per query. There is no equivalent for an $in or $or query.
4. While the operators are documented, it does not seem to be recommended for normal use cases.

Point 3 is a blocker for me (I need to do an $in on the array field), so I'm still looking for another solution.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/oxL8wuVdITA/uWJHVbMd_-8J